# Installing IronPython on Ubuntu Using Mono

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, ironpython

I am trying to install IronPython On Ubuntu 22.04 using Mono. I've followed each of the steps mentioned here - https://davidtavarez.github.io/2018/installing_ironpython/, but I'm still unable to access IPy or IronPython for that matter - It always gives me command not found error.
Do I have to install .Net Core Packages as well, because I am able to run/execute C# files using Mono. I'm fairly new to C# and IronPython and I've tried scoured a lot, but there isn't much material available for using IronPython on Linux.
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a very old post so you should abandon it.

The latest IronPython releases clearly move to .NET Core instead of Mono,

https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/releases/tag/v3.4.1

> You might also read [this post](https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/) to learn why you should stay away from Mono.

Comment: Thank You. It was really simple. I do not know why I needlessly complicated it. I just downloaded the ironpython_3.4.1.deb file and ran sudo apt install ./ironpython_3.4.1.deb. It was that simple. Now when I run ipy it opens up the Iron Python interpretor. Thank You again, so much.